# Problem with install GeoDjango Could not find the GDAL library

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I followed with instruction: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/ for Windows 10
I downloaded Postgres and added installed Postgis. Then OSGeo4W in the folder C:\OSGeo4W and maked point **Modify Windows environment**

I create new project and one application.

In settings.py added:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'geodjango',
        'USER': 'geo',
    },
}
```

After run py manage.py runserver I get a error:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal303", "gdal302", "gdal301", "gdal300", "gdal204", "gdal203", "gdal202", "gdal201", "gdal20"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIB
RARY_PATH in your settings.

I add **(Python Root)\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py "gdal305"**, becauuse this file i have in  C:\OSGeo4W\bin.
I get a error: FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdal305.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax. (this path is good )
In settings.py I add: GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = r'C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdal505', but I'm showing the same error as before.
So I try in settings.py:

```
import os
if os.name == 'nt':
    import platform
    OSGEO4W = r"C:\OSGeo4W"
    if '64' in platform.architecture()[0]:
        OSGEO4W += "64"
    assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
    os.environ['OSGEO4W_ROOT'] = OSGEO4W
    os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\gdal"
    os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\proj"
    os.environ['PATH'] = OSGEO4W + r"\bin;" + os.environ['PATH']
```

And I still get the same error : FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdal305.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

The Python version 3.9.2 64bit
In the moment when I want to check a version OSGeo4W i get information, that don't find a file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JpK0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSox2.png)

Please about more tips.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have gdal305.dll in your OSGEO4W/bin folder. If it is there, then check whether you included gdal305 in your libgdal.py file.

```
elif os.name == "nt":
    # Windows NT shared libraries
    lib_names = [
        "gdal305",
        "gdal304",
        "gdal303",
        "gdal302",
        "gdal301",
        "gdal300",
        "gdal204",
        "gdal203",
        "gdal202",
        "gdal201",
        "gdal20",
    ]
```

Then restart your application and check whether it is working.